# SQL rolling 28 day average since previous Tuesday

Tags: sql-server

I need to calculate a rolling 28-day average based on day of week since the previous Tuesday.  So from DateStamp, I can get the following:

```
(datestamp+1-datepart(weekday, datestamp+5)) as Tuesday
datepart(weekday,DateStamp) as WeekDayNum
```

If the below were a table in Excel, pseudo-code in the fourth column (assuming the two above were available) would look something like this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS([DailySales],[DateStamp],">="&[@Tuesday]-28,[DateStamp],"<"&[@Tuesday],[StoreID],[@StoreID],[WeekdayNum],[@WeekdayNum])
```

So basically for each day of the week, I'm averaging 4 data points.

Here's a sample data set:

| DateStamp | StoreID | DailySales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-1 | 0230 | 6978.18 |
| 2020-12-1 | 0231 | 2952.64 |
| 2020-12-2 | 0230 | 3346.44 |
| 2020-12-2 | 0231 | 1171.74 |
| 2020-12-3 | 0230 | 7253.61 |
| 2020-12-3 | 0231 | 2546.55 |
| 2020-12-4 | 0230 | 759.41 |
| 2020-12-4 | 0231 | 701.69 |
| 2020-12-5 | 0230 | 2709.39 |
| 2020-12-5 | 0231 | 884.5 |
| 2020-12-6 | 0230 | 1795.58 |
| 2020-12-6 | 0231 | 2529.76 |
| 2020-12-7 | 0230 | 3454.64 |
| 2020-12-7 | 0231 | 3378 |
| 2020-12-8 | 0230 | 2376.15 |
| 2020-12-8 | 0231 | 5530.28 |
| 2020-12-9 | 0230 | 667.42 |
| 2020-12-9 | 0231 | 742.53 |
| 2020-12-10 | 0230 | 1246.98 |
| 2020-12-10 | 0231 | 1390.54 |
| 2020-12-11 | 0230 | 2900.85 |
| 2020-12-11 | 0231 | 2975.06 |
| 2020-12-12 | 0230 | 505.24 |
| 2020-12-12 | 0231 | 4161.02 |
| 2020-12-13 | 0230 | 343.42 |
| 2020-12-13 | 0231 | 3673.57 |
| 2020-12-14 | 0230 | 971.15 |
| 2020-12-14 | 0231 | 3293.06 |
| 2020-12-15 | 0230 | 10732.5 |
| 2020-12-15 | 0231 | 2032.61 |
| 2020-12-16 | 0230 | 1435.91 |
| 2020-12-16 | 0231 | 2974.87 |
| 2020-12-17 | 0230 | 8782.72 |
| 2020-12-17 | 0231 | 6669.7 |
| 2020-12-18 | 0230 | 4844.52 |
| 2020-12-18 | 0231 | 4939.37 |
| 2020-12-19 | 0230 | 8414.46 |
| 2020-12-19 | 0231 | 4319.32 |
| 2020-12-20 | 0230 | 1623.25 |
| 2020-12-20 | 0231 | 10730.4 |
| 2020-12-21 | 0230 | 468.86 |
| 2020-12-21 | 0231 | 5573.96 |
| 2020-12-22 | 0230 | 970.43 |
| 2020-12-22 | 0231 | 14583.55 |
| 2020-12-23 | 0230 | 2550.53 |
| 2020-12-23 | 0231 | 961.46 |
| 2020-12-24 | 0230 | 541.19 |
| 2020-12-24 | 0231 | 480.22 |
| 2020-12-26 | 0230 | 2077.46 |
| 2020-12-26 | 0231 | 4444.48 |
| 2020-12-27 | 0230 | 500.02 |
| 2020-12-27 | 0231 | 5203.68 |
| 2020-12-28 | 0230 | 3001.62 |
| 2020-12-28 | 0231 | 2944.84 |
| 2020-12-29 | 0230 | 507.54 |
| 2020-12-29 | 0231 | 9980.34 |
| 2020-12-30 | 0230 | 3646.58 |
| 2020-12-30 | 0231 | 2280.9 |
| 2020-12-31 | 0230 | 818.78 |
| 2020-12-31 | 0231 | 1786.65 |
| 2021-1-2 | 0230 | 1174 |
| 2021-1-2 | 0231 | 3919.76 |
| 2021-1-3 | 0230 | 929.56 |
| 2021-1-3 | 0231 | 1728.31 |
| 2021-1-4 | 0230 | 1768.55 |
| 2021-1-4 | 0231 | 3510.57 |
| 2021-1-5 | 0230 | 2740.26 |
| 2021-1-5 | 0231 | 7827.08 |
| 2021-1-6 | 0230 | 5429.5 |
| 2021-1-6 | 0231 | 1415.73 |
| 2021-1-7 | 0230 | 2518.84 |
| 2021-1-7 | 0231 | 2497.84 |
| 2021-1-8 | 0230 | 1366.57 |
| 2021-1-8 | 0231 | 3815.87 |
| 2021-1-9 | 0230 | 628.16 |
| 2021-1-9 | 0231 | 1274.79 |
| 2021-1-10 | 0230 | 375.99 |
| 2021-1-10 | 0231 | 1038.9 |
| 2021-1-11 | 0230 | 1081.46 |
| 2021-1-11 | 0231 | 1466.84 |
| 2021-1-12 | 0230 | 1704.89 |
| 2021-1-12 | 0231 | 1937.37 |
| 2021-1-13 | 0230 | 2393.86 |
| 2021-1-13 | 0231 | 1888.64 |
| 2021-1-14 | 0230 | 2920.17 |
| 2021-1-14 | 0231 | 2022.57 |
| 2021-1-15 | 0230 | 1814.29 |
| 2021-1-15 | 0231 | 1001.96 |
| 2021-1-16 | 0230 | 6576.04 |
| 2021-1-16 | 0231 | 7485.34 |
| 2021-1-17 | 0230 | 814.81 |
| 2021-1-17 | 0231 | 4564.34 |
| 2021-1-18 | 0230 | 2869.94 |
| 2021-1-18 | 0231 | 1068.95 |
| 2021-1-19 | 0230 | 4603.54 |
| 2021-1-19 | 0231 | 2306.57 |
| 2021-1-20 | 0230 | 1339.23 |
| 2021-1-20 | 0231 | 4092.1 |
| 2021-1-21 | 0230 | 2145.86 |
| 2021-1-21 | 0231 | 12138.5 |
| 2021-1-22 | 0230 | 2418.59 |
| 2021-1-22 | 0231 | 7735.85 |
| 2021-1-23 | 0230 | 3772.35 |
| 2021-1-23 | 0231 | 1965.2 |
| 2021-1-24 | 0230 | 4534.03 |
| 2021-1-24 | 0231 | 2994.9 |
| 2021-1-25 | 0230 | 702.87 |
| 2021-1-25 | 0231 | 631.4 |
| 2021-1-26 | 0230 | 1632.65 |
| 2021-1-26 | 0231 | 2986.1 |

Sorry, there's probably a better way to have done that, but I wanted to make it as simple as possible.

I can do a BASIC rolling 28-day average with the windowing function:

```
select *
    ,Rolling28 = avg(DailySales) over (Partition by StoreID order by datestamp rows between 28 preceding and current row)
From ytd_sales
order by storeid, datestamp
```

However, I'm stuck on getting from there to something that looks like this (shortened) result:

| DateStamp | StoreID | Past_28_AVG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-1-24 | 0230 | 655.1 |
| 2021-1-24 | 0231 | 3133.81 |
| 2021-1-25 | 0230 | 2180.39 |
| 2021-1-25 | 0231 | 2247.8 |
| 2021-1-26 | 0230 | 2389.06 |
| 2021-1-26 | 0231 | 5512.84 |

Comment: Must be me, but the part "_based on day of week since the previous Tuesday_" got me puzzled. From the first row of your expected result: which 4 dates are you averaging to get to 655.1?

Comment: 1/17, 1/10, 1/3, and 12/27.  The previous Tuesday for 1/24 is 1/19, so it'd be the 28 days prior to that.  Since 1/24 is a Sunday, it'd be the four Sundays I listed here, all for StoreID 0230.  The data is random in my example, but we have sales trends largely based on day of the week that we're using to predict the upcoming sales for scheduling and other such purposes.  28 days helps with seasonal trends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a couple `cross apply` joins to reach a solution.

1. First fetch the previous Tuesday (or the current date if it is a Tuesday).
2. Then select the 4 dates based on the previous result.

**Sample data**

```
create table Sales
(
  DateStamp date,
  StoreId nvarchar(4),
  DailySales money
);

insert into Sales (DateStamp, StoreID, DailySales) values
('2020-12-1'    ,'0230',    6978.18),
('2020-12-1'    ,'0231',    2952.64),
('2020-12-2'    ,'0230',    3346.44),
('2020-12-2'    ,'0231',    1171.74),
('2020-12-3'    ,'0230',    7253.61),
('2020-12-3'    ,'0231',    2546.55),
('2020-12-4'    ,'0230',    759.41),
('2020-12-4'    ,'0231',    701.69),
('2020-12-5'    ,'0230',    2709.39),
('2020-12-5'    ,'0231',    884.5),
('2020-12-6'    ,'0230',    1795.58),
('2020-12-6'    ,'0231',    2529.76),
('2020-12-7'    ,'0230',    3454.64),
('2020-12-7'    ,'0231',    3378),
('2020-12-8'    ,'0230',    2376.15),
('2020-12-8'    ,'0231',    5530.28),
('2020-12-9'    ,'0230',    667.42),
('2020-12-9'    ,'0231',    742.53),
('2020-12-10'   ,'0230',    1246.98),
('2020-12-10'   ,'0231',    1390.54),
('2020-12-11'   ,'0230',    2900.85),
('2020-12-11'   ,'0231',    2975.06),
('2020-12-12'   ,'0230',    505.24),
('2020-12-12'   ,'0231',    4161.02),
('2020-12-13'   ,'0230',    343.42),
('2020-12-13'   ,'0231',    3673.57),
('2020-12-14'   ,'0230',    971.15),
('2020-12-14'   ,'0231',    3293.06),
('2020-12-15'   ,'0230',    10732.5),
('2020-12-15'   ,'0231',    2032.61),
('2020-12-16'   ,'0230',    1435.91),
('2020-12-16'   ,'0231',    2974.87),
('2020-12-17'   ,'0230',    8782.72),
('2020-12-17'   ,'0231',    6669.7),
('2020-12-18'   ,'0230',    4844.52),
('2020-12-18'   ,'0231',    4939.37),
('2020-12-19'   ,'0230',    8414.46),
('2020-12-19'   ,'0231',    4319.32),
('2020-12-20'   ,'0230',    1623.25),
('2020-12-20'   ,'0231',    10730.4),
('2020-12-21'   ,'0230',    468.86),
('2020-12-21'   ,'0231',    5573.96),
('2020-12-22'   ,'0230',    970.43),
('2020-12-22'   ,'0231',    14583.55),
('2020-12-23'   ,'0230',    2550.53),
('2020-12-23'   ,'0231',    961.46),
('2020-12-24'   ,'0230',    541.19),
('2020-12-24'   ,'0231',    480.22),
('2020-12-26'   ,'0230',    2077.46),
('2020-12-26'   ,'0231',    4444.48),
('2020-12-27'   ,'0230',    500.02),
('2020-12-27'   ,'0231',    5203.68),
('2020-12-28'   ,'0230',    3001.62),
('2020-12-28'   ,'0231',    2944.84),
('2020-12-29'   ,'0230',    507.54),
('2020-12-29'   ,'0231',    9980.34),
('2020-12-30'   ,'0230',    3646.58),
('2020-12-30'   ,'0231',    2280.9),
('2020-12-31'   ,'0230',    818.78),
('2020-12-31'   ,'0231',    1786.65),
('2021-1-2'     ,'0230',    1174),
('2021-1-2'     ,'0231',    3919.76),
('2021-1-3'     ,'0230',    929.56),
('2021-1-3'     ,'0231',    1728.31),
('2021-1-4'     ,'0230',    1768.55),
('2021-1-4'     ,'0231',    3510.57),
('2021-1-5'     ,'0230',    2740.26),
('2021-1-5'     ,'0231',    7827.08),
('2021-1-6'     ,'0230',    5429.5),
('2021-1-6'     ,'0231',    1415.73),
('2021-1-7'     ,'0230',    2518.84),
('2021-1-7'     ,'0231',    2497.84),
('2021-1-8'     ,'0230',    1366.57),
('2021-1-8'     ,'0231',    3815.87),
('2021-1-9'     ,'0230',    628.16),
('2021-1-9'     ,'0231',    1274.79),
('2021-1-10'    ,'0230',    375.99),
('2021-1-10'    ,'0231',    1038.9),
('2021-1-11'    ,'0230',    1081.46),
('2021-1-11'    ,'0231',    1466.84),
('2021-1-12'    ,'0230',    1704.89),
('2021-1-12'    ,'0231',    1937.37),
('2021-1-13'    ,'0230',    2393.86),
('2021-1-13'    ,'0231',    1888.64),
('2021-1-14'    ,'0230',    2920.17),
('2021-1-14'    ,'0231',    2022.57),
('2021-1-15'    ,'0230',    1814.29),
('2021-1-15'    ,'0231',    1001.96),
('2021-1-16'    ,'0230',    6576.04),
('2021-1-16'    ,'0231',    7485.34),
('2021-1-17'    ,'0230',    814.81),
('2021-1-17'    ,'0231',    4564.34),
('2021-1-18'    ,'0230',    2869.94),
('2021-1-18'    ,'0231',    1068.95),
('2021-1-19'    ,'0230',    4603.54),
('2021-1-19'    ,'0231',    2306.57),
('2021-1-20'    ,'0230',    1339.23),
('2021-1-20'    ,'0231',    4092.1),
('2021-1-21'    ,'0230',    2145.86),
('2021-1-21'    ,'0231',    12138.5),
('2021-1-22'    ,'0230',    2418.59),
('2021-1-22'    ,'0231',    7735.85),
('2021-1-23'    ,'0230',    3772.35),
('2021-1-23'    ,'0231',    1965.2),
('2021-1-24'    ,'0230',    4534.03),
('2021-1-24'    ,'0231',    2994.9),
('2021-1-25'    ,'0230',    702.87),
('2021-1-25'    ,'0231',    631.4),
('2021-1-26'    ,'0230',    1632.65),
('2021-1-26'    ,'0231',    2986.1);
```

**Solution**

```
select s.DateStamp,
    -- pt.DateStamp as PreviousTuesday,
       s.StoreId,
       ra.Avg28
from Sales s
cross apply ( select top 1 s2.DateStamp
              from Sales s2
              where s2.StoreId = s.StoreId
                and s2.DateStamp <= s.DateStamp
                and datepart(weekday, s2.DateStamp) = 3 -- Tuesday
              order by s2.DateStamp desc ) pt -- previous Tuesday
cross apply ( select avg(s3.DailySales) as Avg28
              from Sales s3
              where s3.StoreId = s.StoreId
                and datepart(weekday, s3.DateStamp) = datepart(weekday, s.DateStamp)
                and s3.DateStamp < pt.DateStamp
                and s3.DateStamp >= dateadd(day, -28, pt.DateStamp)) ra -- rolling average
```

**Result**

```
DateStamp   StoreId  Avg28
----------  -------  ---------
...         ...      ... 
2021-01-24  0230      655.095
2021-01-24  0231     3133.8075
2021-01-25  0230     2180.3925
2021-01-25  0231     2247.8
2021-01-26  0230     2389.0575
2021-01-26  0231     5512.84
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/777327/9) to see things in action.

Comment: I'm glad I asked, as I'm confident I'd never have solved this on my own.  I tested this with my live data and comparing with my Excel results, this is exactly correct.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Additional note:  The flexibility of this method allows me to easily add columns in the table and generate additional calculations within ra or in some instances just replicate ra to a third cross apply and eliminate the datepart match (for instance) for items where that's not as important.  Such a useful solution.